Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed | Laravel project
Auctions table
class CreateAuctionsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('auctions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('car_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('current_bid_id');
            $table->boolean('queue')->default(true);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('current_price')->default(0);
            $table->foreign('car_id')->references('id')->on('cars')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('current_bid_id')->references('id')->on('bids')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('auctions');
    }
}

Bids table
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateBidsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('bids', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('auction_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('amount');
            $table->foreign('auction_id')->references('id')->on('auctions')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('bids');
    }
}


when im trying to migrate (php artisan migrate:fresh), theres a problem:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table usedcars.auctions(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter tableauctionsadd constraintauctions_current_bid_id_foreign foreign key (current_bid_id) references bids (id) on delete cascade)
Honestly I don`t know what to do, Ive tried almost everything...
Auction migration is first, then bids.
Thank you guys for any help.

your auctions table has a foreign key pointing to the bids table which hasn't been created yet ...... you have a circle of foreign key dependencies so you can't do this ... you would need to make a 3rd migration to alter the auctions table after the bids table has been created that would add the foreign key to bids

Does your cars & users table is already created or both of these migrations files are yet to be executed? If your both cars & users tables are already created then this migration issue can be solved within a minutes.
